# Can I make this PowerShell Script accept commas?

Tags: powershell, weather

The following powershell script outputs the results twice when there is a comma. It separates the strings as two entries. How can I make it treat it as one string instead of two?

```
Function Get-Weather {
    [Alias('Wttr')]
    [Cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
            [Parameter(
                Mandatory = $true,
                HelpMessage = 'Enter name of the City to get weather report',
                ValueFromPipeline = $true,
                Position = 0
            )]
            [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
            [string[]] $City,
            [switch] $Tomorrow,
            [switch] $DayAfterTomorrow
    )

    Process
    {
        Foreach($Item in $City){
            try {

                # Check Operating System Version
                If((Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem).caption -like "*Windows 10*") {
                    $Weather = $(Invoke-WebRequest "http://wttr.in/$City" -UserAgent curl -UseBasicParsing).content -split "`n"
                }
                else {
                    $Weather = (Invoke-WebRequest "http://wttr.in/$City" -UseBasicParsing).ParsedHtml.body.outerText  -split "`n"
                }

                If($Weather)
                {
                    $Weather[0..16]
                    If($Tomorrow){ $Weather[17..26] }
                    If($DayAfterTomorrow){ $Weather[27..36] }
                }
            }
            catch {
                $_.exception.Message
            }
        }            
    }

}

Get-Weather Shrewsbury,MA?n1
```

Comment: Commas are array separators in PowerShell. You should either escape them or encase the parameter in double quotes and then write some logic to split your string that contains commas. E.g. Your cmdlet call should be: `Get-Weather "Shrewsbury,MA?n1"` - But make sure you have some function to, perhaps, break the parameter into an array (delimited by the comma) and then use the array index to get whichever part of the parameter the rest of your script needs.

Comment: Perfect thanks. Researching this as a newbie to powershell gave me no straight answers. Very helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also remember that when you use single quotes "single-quotation marks (a single-quoted string), the string is passed to the command exactly as you type it. No substitution is performed." Versus when you use double quotes "double quotation marks (a double-quoted string), variable names that are preceded by a dollar sign ($) are replaced with the variable's value before the string is passed to the command for processing."

This is from: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6 and is for PowerShell 6, but the same rules apply to PowerShell 1 through 6.

So unless you need to use a variable inside the string, the single quotes will force PowerShell to use the string exactly how you have it written.